# Selecting from three Relation with Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I have for ex this Tables

```
Customer{cid, name, phone, address}
Employee{eid, name, positon, salary}
Resp_for{cid,eid}
```

Now I want to ask in relational Algebra that it should print out  all employees that are resposible for the Customer: 'Obama'

I am trying it but not sure that I understand the relational algebra clearly, so I create this:

```
PROJECT   (SELECT                 (Customer x Employeee x Resp_for))
       E.eid       C.name = 'Obama'
                 AND R.cid = C.cid
                 And R.eid = E.eid
```

so how it looks as sql query?

```
SELECT E.eid
FROM Customer JOIN Employee JOIN Resp_for
WHERE C.name = 'Obama'
      AND R.cid = C.cid
      And R.eid = E.eid
```

is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL query for This wil be:-

```
SELECT E.EID FROM CUSTOMERS C, EMPLOYEE E, RESP_FOR R
WHERE E.EID = R.EID
AND R.CID = C.CID
AND C.NAME = 'OBAMA';
```

NOW YOU CAN CONVERT THIS QUERY TO RELATIONAL ALGEBRA.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, though without putting the table aliases (R, C and E) against their respective tables it is unlikely to run.

There is a new form for expressing joins which is more common these days:

```
SELECT E.eid
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN Resp_for R
    ON R.cid = C.cid
INNER JOIN Employee E
    ON E.eid = R.eid
WHERE C.name = 'Obama'
```

Same meaning, different format and IMHO easier to assimilate.

Comment: so I think in the relational algebra that could be πE.eid(σC.Name='Obama'(Customer)))⋈Resp_for⋈Employee)