# Creating Tables a SQL Parentheses syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create in postgresSQL 9.3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  cid INT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
);
CREATE TABLE Product
(   
 producno INT,
 name VARCHAR,
 );
CREATE TABLE Order
 (
  oderid INT,
  shipdate DATE,
  cid INT,
 );
CREATE TABLE Ordered
(
 orderid INT,
 prodno INT,
 );
```

But I get an syntax error on line 5 ')'

SQL Status:42601
So I have already looked in PostgreSQL Error Codes so it says only that it is a syntax error But if I try it with other querys from the internet it works but trying to create my own I get an error

Answer (score 2):

Remove comma from all the last fields

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  cid INT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
);
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  cid INT,
  name VARCHAR(32)
);
```

And so on for others.

Comment: could you maybe help me with a relational algebra?

Comment: ok post that and you have tagged the question with mysql , postgreysql so make sure to specify which database you are trying to do the operation.

Comment: I have now SQL and want to create the RA here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781004/selecting-from-three-relation-with-relational-algebra and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791505/date-in-sql-and-relation-algebra-is-null and I am not sure if I've done it right

Comment: have you checked the answer from Michael Green that does exactly the thing you wanted. Now relational algebra is a representation of entity relations.And queries are basically in the form of SQL not relational expression.You may check http://www.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra/ this which converts a relational algebra to SQL

Comment: you may check this http://www.go4expert.com/articles/relational-algebra-operations-sql-t21166/

Comment: Yeah that the SQL query but I am trying to create the in relational algebra so I think it should look like πE.eid(σC.Name='Obama'(Customer)))⋈Resp_for⋈Employee) but I am not sure if that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54154/discussion-between-kate-and-abhik-chakraborty).

Comment: ok `σC.Name='Obama' = single relation` `σC.Name='Obama'(Customer)))⋈Resp_fo = single rel on Resp_fo`   and so on, it looks correct. And rest is just association in the expression on eid where eid is the joining key. So I would say it looks good. But an expert can give you more details since its been a decade I have not done this and what I learned during my masters with that trying to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

If column start with any number some time pg gives 42601 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
  Position: 107

So pelase check table create sql before execution